# Displaying additional information about elements in dropdown

Tags: forms, dropdown

I need to let users pick 1 or up to many identifiers for an authentication process in a config setup. Each has a name (cant be changed, picked from a dropdown for now as seen below) and a label that can be edited by the user. There are 13 available identifiers to choose from, and each could need a little explanation.

With the current design I would need to use a tooltip or something similar to display information about each element in the dropdown list (or show it once an item is selected, but that is obviously cumbersome for the user). Any ideas of how I could design this in a better way, and let the user easily read information about each option?

[image]

Comment: How long are the explanations?

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics does this. You'll see this interaction in the **Active Users Report** when you try to build a condition. There are a large amount of specific dimensions to choose from, so these tips help quite a bit.

[image]

**Here it is in action:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input. It doesnt suggest an alternative way of solving my problem, but its helpful to see that tooltips can be used this way. I might have to have longer descriptions in the tooltips however, and not sure how that would affect usability.